# How to change a socat tcp4 connection into an SSL connection at a later point (Using XMPP protocol)

Tags: ssl, xmpp, socat

I'm looking at creating a very simple XMPP proxy.  The XMPP protocol starts with plain text and then converts the socket to SSL if supported and continues on.

Here is an example XMPP session, I've trimmed it down to the basic parts:
Checking features:

```
(11:49:48) jabber: Sending (chris@localhost): <?xml version='1.0' ?>
(11:49:48) jabber: Sending (chris@localhost): <stream:stream to='localhost' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
(11:49:48) jabber: Recv (358): <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='localhost' id='5dea6b36-2da5-485a-8bed-16884e56d6f3' xml:lang='en' xmlns='jabber:client'><stream:features><starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'><required/></starttls><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
```

Telling the server to start communicating in SSL and exchange keys:

```
(11:49:48) jabber: Sending (chris@localhost): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
(11:49:48) jabber: Recv (50): <proceed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
(11:49:48) nss: SSL version 3.3 using 256-bit AES with 256-bit SHA256 MAC
Server Auth: 2048-bit RSA, Key Exchange: 2048-bit RSA, Compression: NULL
Cipher Suite Name: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
(11:49:48) certificate: Successfully verified certificate for localhost
```

We are now in an SSL session:

```
(11:49:48) jabber: Sending (ssl) (chris@localhost): <stream:stream to='localhost' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
(11:49:48) jabber: Recv (ssl)(447): <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='localhost' id='74a00818-e037-4405-ada1-02bb3dbfe023' xml:lang='en' xmlns='jabber:client'>
```

When I try to create a socat SSL "server" and connect to it with Pidgin I get unknown protocol:

```
$ socat openssl-listen:5222,reuseaddr,cert=$HOME/server.pem,cafile=$HOME/client.crt,fork -
2016/01/13 14:00:59 socat[28586] E SSL_accept(): error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I tried the same thing with a socat non-SSL "server" and it worked up until it needed to change to SSL (I've added "Client:" and "Server:" to this output for readability.  All the "Server:" lines were pasted by me into the terminal):

```
$ socat tcp4-listen:5222,reuseaddr,fork -
Client: <?xml version='1.0' ?><stream:stream to='localhost' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
Server: <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='localhost' id='5dea6b36-2da5-485a-8bed-16884e56d6f3' xml:lang='en' xmlns='jabber:client'><stream:features><starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'><required/></starttls><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
Client: <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
Server: <proceed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
Client: tp�C?�f�Q��|_pV��j���=�^(�32g98kf�/<5=
```

On the last line the client is now trying to talk to us in SSL, so I need a way to tell socat to switch to SSL at that point.  Socat obviously doesn't know anything about the XMPP protocol so it doesn't know when to switch.  Can socat be told to switch dynamically like that or should I be looking at other ways to do this?

**Edit:** I did some more research.
Many protocols, HTTPS for example use "always encrypted" connections.
XMPP uses starttls which basically means unencrypted connection until the client and server agree to upgrade the connection to encrypted.

**Edit:** I just looked at openssl and it has a -starttls for s_client, but not for s_server which indicates to me that it is an architectural issue, it is tricky to know or be told when and how to upgrade the connection to encrypted.

So I guess my real question is, can socat handle protocols that use starttls with or without some manual intervention to tell it when to switch?  I don't think openssl can.  Is there some other tool that can do this or should I just be writing my own using an SSL library of course?

Comment: Are you still interested in a solution using `socat`? It should be possible to achieve this with a helper shell script which spawns a child ssl socat...

Comment: @vlp I'm using XMPP and discovered that it has a "legacy SSL" mode which is just normal SSL so I've just turned that on and I don't have to worry about the more complicated STARTTLS behaviour.  So I don't really need it any more.  But feel free to have a go at it if you like.  I'll try any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of using SSL/TLS:
XMPP uses STARTTLS where the client and server discuss their security features and then the client requests converting the socket to TLS at an arbitrary point in the communication.
HTTPS and others use two sockets, one for discussing security features and then communication is switched to a second socket setup purely for encrypted communications.

socat:
Does not support STARTTLS.

openssl:
Supports STARTTLS on the client side:

```
openssl s_client -starttls ...
```

On the server side as far as I can tell custom code is required for each situation.  I found [this](https://github.com/ipopov/starttls-mitm/blob/master/mitm_listener.py) useful Python script.